# Cypress: > Cannot call cy.get() outside a running test

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

i am getting this error when i run a test file. The test file uses methods declared in a page object file, please let me know how this can be fixed.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcLZk.png)

[Page Object code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3YTb.png)

```
cy.get('.more-less-container').then(dropdown => {
  if (dropdown.find('.name').contains('More')) {
    cy.get('more-less-container').click();
  } else {
    console.log('folders are in expanded state');
  }
});

class Folders {

  Archive() {
    dropdown();
    cy.get('.category-content')
      .find('[title="Archive"]')
      .click()
      .get('.folder-details')
      .should('contain.text', 'Archive');
  }

  Trash() {
    dropdown();
    cy.get('.category-content')
      .find('[title="Trash"]')
      .click()
      .get('.folder-details')
      .should('contain.text', 'Trash');
  }
```

[Test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7VRl.png)

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import { openFolder } from '../support/page-objects/sidebar/drafts';

describe('Verify mobile app download link redirections', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.login();
  });
});

it('Needs to open the drafts folder', () => {
  openFolder.Drafts();
  cy.get('.modal-close').click();
});
```

Not sure what i'm missing out here.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the `cy.get(...)` command (line 1) in your "Page Object code" file is not part of a class, and as such will be executed as soon as cypress is opened (ran), because that's how this support file is supposed to work, it's loaded and executed immediately (which means before any test are actually started). So the solution would be to move that command as part of the `Folders` class as a utility function, which later on you would explicitly call during your tests.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what i did and it solved the above error.